# Android Wear(Watch). Is there any way to detect that wear is connected to any device or not, from the wear only?

Tags: android, device, wear-os, detect, android-wear-data-api

I have search around the web but no luck. Everywhere there is a solution available for the mobile device only not from the wear. I just want to check from the wear that any android device is connected or not.

Comment: What's the use case for this? The usual solution is to use the Capability API to detect if a handheld *with your app* is connected; would that work for you?

Comment: @String Thanks for the response. The case would be to save data in the watch when it's goes offline and than sync with device when connected(online).

Comment: If you're going to "sync with device when connected", that probably means that you do have an app installed on the handheld, correct?

Comment: @String That is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Given you have an app installed on the handheld that you're trying to detect, you can use the [Capability API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityApi) to be notified when the connection is made or broken. There's a good walkthrough here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#SendMessage